# How to extract soil data from HWSD using arcgis?

Tags: database, arcgis

I need to get soil data from Harmonized World Soils Database (HWSD) to 1000 points. I was successful in connecting the Microsoft Access database provided by HWSD to ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 using Build Raster Attribute Table tool.

But when I use the tool Extract Values to Points in order to obtain the variables data, only values of MU_Global are extracted.

Is there a way to get an attribute table with all the variables for each of my points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still want to use [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm), but make sure you properly set the `add_attributes` parameter.

> Determines if the raster attributes are written to the output point
>   feature dataset.
>
> - VALUE_ONLY — Only the value of the input raster is added to the point attributes. This is the default.
> - ALL — All the fields from the input raster (except Count) will be added to the point attributes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In the box of  Extract Values to Points tool I select the option "Append all the input raster attributes to the output point features (optional)". But, when I run the tool I get error message. I'm only successful when  this option is not selected being extracted only MU_GLOBAL.